# I need to limit SomeId to only 56 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We need the logic below to truncate anything over 56 characters. We always want to remove the tilde, which our solution does but we don't know how to limit the length of SomeId to 56.

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('~', isnull(SomeID,''))= 0 
THEN '1' 
ELSE isnull(RIGHT(isnull(SomeID,''), 
LEN(isnull(SomeID,'')) - CHARINDEX('~', isnull(SomeID,''))), '') END
```

Comment: What is the data type of `SomeId` column?

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to have the database just silently chop off user supplied input. Rather, have the business layer validate incoming data and allow the database to report that data is too wide and fail, should the business layer fail to validate data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, use `LEFT()`:

```
LEFT(CASE WHEN SomeId LIKE '%~%'
          THEN RIGHT(SomeID, LEN(SomeId) - CHARINDEX('~', SomeId))
          ELSE '1'
     END, 56)
```

I rearranged the logic a bit to simplify the code.  You don't need all the checks for `NULL`.